# Designing REST API for resources with one to one relationship

Tags: api, rest, architecture

Imagine Tinder-like aplication. A user registers an Account with email and password, and later on he creates a Profile which can match with other Profiles. There would be one-to-one relationship between an Account and Profile.

For that purpose I would create such endpoints:

```
GET /accounts - for login
POST /accounts - for registration
GET /profiles - to get list of Profiles the user could match with
POST /profiles - to let the user create his own Profile with photos and bio
```

However, the interface should be able to check whether the user has a Profile, before allowing him to swipe Profiles (backend of course should check that too).
To do that we would need an endpoint which gets User's Profile by his Account.id.
How should such endpoint look like?

I'm thinking of:

```
GET /profiles/byAccountId/:accountId
```

I don't like it, but it seems the least dirty approach. Because of one-to-one relationship and the need to fetch one particular resource which we could identify (by the ID), using query parameters on profiles GET endpoint (/profiles?accountId=) doesn't seem right.
On the other hand, 'byAccountId' is not a resource, but a REST controller at most.

What's the proper REST way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Put your profile URI on your account resource.  If you don't have a profile, it's null and can't swipe.